# Expected Value and Variance with Substitution?

Tags: probability

In preparation for a statistics test, I came across this practice question that is causing me a lot of difficulty:

X, Y, and Z are i.i.d random variables with mean = 4 and variance = 1. Let W = $\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$XY - 2Z - $\frac{16}{\sqrt3)}$. Compute E(W) and Var(W).

I'm not quite sure how to approach it. First, I tried simplifying E(W), and got -8, which I don't think is correct:

E(W) = $\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$(E(X)E(Y))- 2E(Z) - $\frac{16}{\sqrt3}$

E(W) = $\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$(4)(4) - 2(4) - $\frac{16}{\sqrt3}$ = - 8

I know that $\operatorname{Var}(W) = E(W^2)-[E(W)^2]$, but that's basically it. Is it just a matter of substituting 1 into the equation? I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have correctly computed
\begin{align}
E[W] &= E\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}XY - 2Z -\frac{16}{\sqrt{3}}\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}E[XY] - 2E[Z] -\frac{16}{\sqrt{3}} &\scriptstyle{\text{linearity of expectation}}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}E[X]E[Y] - 2E[Z] -\frac{16}{\sqrt{3}}
&\scriptstyle{X~\text{and}~Y~\text{are independent}}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\times 4 \times 4 - 2\times 4 - \frac{16}{\sqrt{3}}\\
&= -8.
\end{align}
You made a correct start to finding the variance of $W$ as $\operatorname{Var}(W) = E(W^2)-(E[W])^2$. You know the value of $(E[W])^2$ already from the above. Now all that remains is to figure out
$$E[W^2] = E\left[\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}XY - 2Z -\frac{16}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2\right]$$
which you can do by multiplying out the square. You will get six terms of which one will have $X^2Y^2$ in it, another $Z^2$ in it, yet another $XYZ$, and one with $XY$ in it. Use *linearity of expectation* to write $E[W^2]$ as the sum of six expectations, and then use *independence of* $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ to write $E[XYZ]$ as $E[X]E[Y]E[Z]$ etc. Don't forget that $E[X^2] = \operatorname{Var}(X) + (E[X])^2$ etc.  Good luck!

### ----------------

Since writing the above, BruceET, in a comment that he regrettably declines to incorporate into his own answer, has come up with a much simpler computation for $\operatorname{Var}(W)$. Since comments are ephemeral and can de deleted at any time by the author, I am memorializing this method below.

Since $XY$ and $Z$ are independent random variables,
$$\operatorname{Var}(W) = \operatorname{Var}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}XY - 2Z -\frac{16}{\sqrt{3}}\right) = \frac{1}{{3}}\operatorname{Var}(XY)+4\operatorname{Var}(Z).$$ 
We of course know that $\operatorname{Var}(Z) = 1$, while
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(XY) &= E[(XY)^2] - \left(E[XY]\right)^2\\
&= E[X^2Y^2] - \left(E[XY]\right)^2\\
&= E[X^2]E[Y^2] - \left(E[X]E[Y]\right)^2\\
&= \left(\operatorname{Var}(X)+(E[X])^2\right)\left(\operatorname{Var}(Y)+(E[Y])^2\right)- \left(E[X]E[Y]\right)^2\\
&= 17^2-16^2\\
&= (17+16)(17-16)\\
&= 33
\end{align}
leading to
$$\operatorname{Var}(W) = \frac{1}{{3}}\operatorname{Var}(XY)+4\operatorname{Var}(Z) = 15.$$
And that's it. No fuss, no complicated calculations, no million simulations yielding a sample variance of $14.99188$ which R rounds off to $15$ as the *approximate* value of the variance, instead of the above direct *mathematical* computation giving the *exact* value of the variance as $15$. Ah well, *de gustibus non est disputandam*.....

Comment: Too much? Given $E(X)=E(Y)=4,$ easy to see $E(X^2)=E(Y^2)=17,$ so $V(XY) = 17^2-16^2 = 33.$ Whence $V(W) = \frac 13V(XY)+4V(Z)=\frac 13(33) + 4(1) = 15.$

Comment: @BruceET Include that calculation at the _top_ of your own answer (whether you delete the rest of it is up to you) and I will remove my downvote.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration, but I like my answer just as it is--for reasons previously explained. Especially the use of simulation. It's not that I object to making edits based on comments. Make them regularly, when I've gotten something wrong. But not this time.

Comment: Re the edit: there's something amiss in the calculations; in particular, (17+16)-(17-16)=32, not 33.  Therein lies the merit of doing a quick simulation *as a check on the mathematical computation:* without some indication of the correct answer, you likely would have accepted 32 as the value and not 33, leading to a wrong result; but even a small simulation would have shown you the error.  I believe that to be the point of @BruceET's answer.

Comment: @whuber The errors you noted (which I have just fixed) were _typographical_ errors that I did not notice before I posted the edited answer. I would _not_ have accepted 32 as the final result for $\operatorname{var}(XY)$.

Comment: My point is that it's so easy for mistakes to creep into a mathematical calculation, even when they are only typographical errors.  You seem bent on criticizing the use of simulation to check mathematical answers to probability questions and this provided a very nice example of what simulation offers.

Comment: @whuber I was criticizing, and continue to criticize, BruceET's answer because he provided only a simulation and not the mathematical calculation (the mathematical calculation was in the first comment in this thread). So, the _original answer_ had _no_ basis for asserting that the variance was $15$ (in fact, R only said that the variance was _approximately_$15$). I have no objections to the use of simulation to _check_ mathematical answers to probability questions but have strong objections to simulation being presented as the _only_ answer without any obvious effort at analysis. (continued)

Comment: @whuber Let's assume that BruceET had actually solved the problem analytically _before_ he ran the simulation. Then why not say so, even if it just to say "The variance of $W$ is $15$ as can be shown analytically but here I will present just a simulation in R to confirm this result numerically". Why not include just these words, if not the complete proof that he wrote in his comment, as an _edit_ to his answer? The way BruceET's answer is written makes in sound like simulation is the only way to go.

Comment: Based on the many and consistently excellent contributions to this site by @BruceET, it's safe to make that assumption.  I agree that the logic in the answer could be clarified in the way you suggest (and would be an improvement).  The reason for formulating the answer in that way was to follow the [tag:self-study] tag wiki, as he explained in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. You've already seen what is perhaps the deepest part---that $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$ because $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Here is a simulation, in R, of a million realizations of $W$ to the given specifications. It is reasonable to expect two or three significant digits of
accuracy.

```
set.seed(928)
m = 10^6;  mu = 4;  sg = 1
x = rnorm(m,mu,sg);  y = rnorm(m,mu,sg);  z = rnorm(m,mu,sg)
w = (1/sqrt(3))*x*y - 2*z - 16/sqrt(3)
mean(w); var(w)
[1] -8.000974    # aprx E(W) = -8
[1] 14.99188     # aprx Var(W) = 15
```

Beyond your question: $W$ is slightly right-skewed (because of the product
term), so that the simulated distribution of $W$ is not a really close match to
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=-8,\sigma=\sqrt{15}).$

[image]

Comment: No, the hardest part is figuring out what $E[W^2]$ is since $W^2$ is a sum of terms including $XYZ$ and we need to use the independence of $X$, $Y$, _and_ $Z$ to deal with that. Your rush to use R misses all the stuff that the OP needs to learn.

Comment: It seemed to me from reading the question that OP has learned what is needed. Relationship btw $Var(W), E(W^2),$ and $E(W)$ clearly on display. $E(X^2Y^2) = E(X^2)E(Y^2)$ parallels what OP has already figured out. The simulation in R was a way to show answers without actually doing the problem, which I try to avoid on 'self-study'-type problems--even if not so ID'd. As always, willing to discuss with OP if requested. // If you disagree, why not give your own answer based on your assessment of the question.

Comment: Well, I do disagree and have written my own answer to teach the OP what _I_ think he needs to learn.